# Azure AD login fails

Tags: azure-active-directory, wso2-identity-server, ws-federation

I tried to configure AzureADJoin with WSO2 IS　according to the following Youtube.

*https://systemsdigest.com/videos/using-wso2-identity-server-microsoft-aad-join
*
But I received following Error when I tried login to Azure AD.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkJnj.png)

The following settings have been changed from Youtube.

- Set "Subject Claim URI" under "Claim Configuration" in "Service Providers" to "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ7Ex.png)

I confirmed that the issuer listed in the SAML response and the issuer set in AzureAD is the same.
The version of WSO2　IS is 5.10.

I would like to know how to solve this error.